# How to Efficiently Retrieve Facebook Page Post Insights, Likes, Comments, and Follower Count with respect to time?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, automation

I've been struggling to find an efficient way to obtain Facebook Page post insights, including the number of likes, comments, and the follower count. So far, I haven't come across any specific API endpoints for this, and the only workaround I've found is to iterate through each post and filter the likes and comments, which seems highly inefficient.

I'm wondering if there's a more efficient method to get real-time updates on likes, comments, and follower count for a Facebook Page. Can I use the since and then parameters or any other techniques to achieve this without the need for time-consuming iteration?

Any guidance or insights on this matter would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance.

I tried very thing in documentation but didn't seem to find any solution